# Which Mockserver to use when dealing with different webservices (Rest and SOAP)?

Tags: mocking, wiremock, mockserver

I do have a lot of experiences in automation testing and testing API and SOAP with SoapUi for example, but I never use a mock server. 
It's actually make a lot of sense to use it.

For my purpose of testing I have the following requirements :

- Mocking Webservices (Rest and SOAP)
- An UI for settings and easy collaboration with other teams
- Can be install on own server

I found a lot of FOSS :

- Mockserver: https://www.mock-server.com/
- Wiremock: http://wiremock.org/
- Castlerock: https://castlemock.com/

Is there any other open source tools which match the requirements? Which tool bring more for automation testing and easy setup (UI)?

Thank you

Comment: doi yu find a way to load soap form castlemock or the others ?